# selenium regular expression such as id=regexp:.* doesn't work

Tags: regex, selenium

I have an .aspx page and I'm trying to locate a textbox via the selenium UI. The id is: `p_lt_ctl01_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_SignUpFree_txtFirstName`

I've tried: `id=*._txtFirstName`
and: `id=glob:*_txtFirstName`

Is there a better way other than CSS to locate a textbox whose id may change each time it's compiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put wildcards in an `id` "selector". Either you use `id=whole_id_here` or don't.

Fortunately, for your case, you can use the CSS selector:

```
[id*=_txtFirstName]
```

**In Selenium IDE, use it like:**

```
css=[id*=_txtFirstName]
```

Example Selenium IDE source snippet:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>css=[id*=_txtFirstName]</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${x}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

---

<sub>**Note:** If `_txtFirstName` is always at the end, you can also use the CSS locator with `$` instead of `*` (it is more restrictive, will only match if it is at the end, while `*` matches if it is anywhere): `[id$=_txtFirstName]`.               (In Selenium IDE, naturally, use it like: `css=[id$=_txtFirstName]`.)</sub>

Comment: That seems like it should work but when I'm in the Firefox add-on it doesn't find it.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer to make it clearer. To use the wildcard, you must specify it is a CSS selector by using the prefix `css=` (instead of `id=`).

Comment: Thx! This worked. I also was able to finally get the XPath version to work as well but the CSS one is simpler. XPath version: //*[contains(@id,'_txtFirstName')]

Comment: hahah did you even read my answer. :P it was posted 1 hr ago with the xpath solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `contains`

```
[contains(@id,'_txtFirstName')]
```

Comment: Thx. Adding //* allows this to work as well. ie: //*[contains(@id,'_txtFirstName')]